# How to create new column with values that are separated by comma and exist in another column in sql

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 2 columns:

- 1 column that holds a single IP
- 1 column that holds multiple IPs separated by comma, i need to extract every ip
- Single IP col has one-to-many relationship with multiple IP col.  So I need to do partitioning but prior to that split every IP form the multiple IPs.

I cannot present any data as those are IPs from my work but here's an example.

```
Single IP col  |  Multiple IP col |
11.111.111.111 |  11.111.111.112,11.222.222.113, etc
22.222.222.222 |  10.115.125.112,07.122.222.153, etc
33.333.333.333 |  12.112.112.113,08.333.333.456, etc
```

The desired outcome would be like:

```
Single IP col  |  Multiple IP col 
11.111.111.111 |  11.111.111.112
11.111.111.111 |  11.222.222.113 
22.222.222.222 |  10.115.125.112
22.222.222.222 |  07.122.222.153 
33.333.333.333 |  12.112.112.113
33.333.333.333 |  08.333.333.456
```

Split_part() will not suffice as the number of IPs in the Multiple cols is not fixed.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I managed to count the number of IPs in the multiple IPs column by using regexp_count.
The next step would be to create a loop function and use split_part(string,delimiter,counter) while counter <= regexp_count, but I still struggle with vertica so far.
Is there any way to achieve this partition without creating a function? I dont see how can I loop though without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the comma-separated list of ip addresses to an array, using `STRING_TO_ARRAY()`, and `EXPLODE()` the whole `OVER(PARTITION BEST)`:

```
WITH
indata(Single_IP_col,Multiple_IP_col,rest) AS (
          SELECT '11.111.111.111','11.111.111.112,11.222.222.113', 'etc'
UNION ALL SELECT '22.222.222.222','10.115.125.112,07.122.222.153', 'etc'
UNION ALL SELECT '33.333.333.333','12.112.112.113,08.333.333.456', 'etc'
)
SELECT
  EXPLODE(
    single_ip_col
  , STRING_TO_ARRAY(multiple_ip_col)
  , rest
  )
  OVER(PARTITION BEST)
  AS (single_ip_col,idx,tgt_ip,rest)
FROM indata;
 single_ip_col  | idx |     tgt_ip     | rest 
----------------+-----+----------------+------
 11.111.111.111 |   0 | 11.111.111.112 | etc
 11.111.111.111 |   1 | 11.222.222.113 | etc
 22.222.222.222 |   0 | 10.115.125.112 | etc
 22.222.222.222 |   1 | 07.122.222.153 | etc
 33.333.333.333 |   0 | 12.112.112.113 | etc
 33.333.333.333 |   1 | 08.333.333.456 | etc
```